# difference between url_beg and path_beg in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Haproxy doc prefers using path_beg over url_beg to match path in urls.

As per https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#url:

```
With ACLs, using "path" is preferred over using "url", because clients may send a full URL as is normally done with proxies.
```

Seems that in above case url_beg wont work, I didn't understand what does it mean. Can I have curl send full url as is which will not be matched by `url_beg` but `path_beg` will match it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepare haproxy for some non-standard requests too. Take a look at this weird `GET`:

```
$ echo -ne "GET http://google.com/books/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n" | nc -v google.com 80
Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://books.google.com/books/
...
```

For comparison, the standard way:

```
$ echo -ne "GET /books/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n" | nc -v google.com 80
Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://books.google.com/books/
...
```

And how to produce the same weird GET with `curl`:

```
$ curl -v --request-target http://google.com/books/ http://google.com/books/
*   Trying 172.217.16.14...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.16.14) port 80 (#0)
> GET http://google.com/books/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://books.google.com/books/
```

Comment: what curl version you are using, my both versions `7.29.0` and `7.54.0` dont have `--request-target` option

Comment: @DeepakDeore Check User-Agent header above.